# Is there a complete example to write a mathematical expression in sympy to a Microsoft Word document?

Tags: sympy, docx

this might be a silly question. But I am desperate. I am a math teacher and I try to generate Math tests. I tried Python for this and I get some things done. However, I am not a professional programmer, so I get lost with MathMl, prettyprint() and whatsoever.

Is there anybody who can supply me a complete example that I can execute? It may just contain one small silly equation, that does not matter. I just want to see how I can get it into a Word document. After that, I can use that as a basis. I work on a Mac.

I hope anyone can help me out. Thanks in advance!

Best regards, Johan

Comment: You might want to look into the .odt format, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755682/how-to-add-math-formulas-in-odt-document-using-odfpy

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
from sympy import *
from docx import Document
from lxml import etree

# create expression
x, y = symbols('x y')
expr1 = (x+y)**2

# create MathML structure
expr1xml = mathml(expr1, printer = 'presentation')
tree = etree.fromstring('<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">'+expr1xml+'</math>')

# convert to MS Office structure
xslt = etree.parse('C:/MML2OMML.XSL')
transform = etree.XSLT(xslt)
new_dom = transform(tree)

# write to docx
document = Document()
p = document.add_paragraph()
p._element.append(new_dom.getroot())
document.save("simpleEq.docx")
```

Comment: You reference a file in your solution: 'C:/MML2OMML.XSL'. What is this file? Where did you acquire it? It seems to be a critical part of your process. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

How about the following. The `capture` captures whatever is printed. In this case I use `pprint` to print the expression that I want written to file. There are lots of options you can use with `pprint` (including wrapping which you might want to set to False). The quality of output will depend on the fonts you use. I don't do this at all so I don't have a lot of hints for that.

```
from pprint import pprint
from sympy.utilities.iterables import capture
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy import Integral
with open('out.doc','w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(capture(lambda:pprint(Integral(x**2, (x, 1, 3)))))
```

When I double click (in Windows) on the out.doc file, a word equation with the integral appears.

Here is the actual IPython session:

```
IPython console for SymPy 1.6.dev (Python 3.7.3-32-bit) (ground types: python)

These commands were executed:
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
>>> k, m, n = symbols('k m n', integer=True)
>>> f, g, h = symbols('f g h', cls=Function)
>>> init_printing()

Documentation can be found at https://docs.sympy.org/dev


In [1]: pprint(Integral(x**2, (x, 1, 3)))
3
(
?  2
? x  dx
)
1

In [2]: from pprint import pprint
   ...: from sympy.utilities.iterables import capture
   ...: from sympy.abc import x
   ...: from sympy import Integral
   ...: with open('out.doc','w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
   ...:     f.write(capture(lambda:pprint(Integral(x**2, (x, 1, 3)))))
   ...:
```

{problems pasting the unicode here, but it shows up as an integral symbol in console}

Comment: This just outputs `Integral(x**2, (x, 1, 3))` as text. I don't think there is a simple solution for this as .doc files don't support pretty equations and the .docx file structure is rather complicated (it is a zip archive, essentially). A best bet would be to generate a LaTeX markup and then translate that to PDF.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-docx/nQfRAZc80Co this could help a bit

Comment: If it looks like `Integral(...)` then unicode pretty printing was not initialized. You should see an actual integral sign and superscript 2 on the x.

Comment: Thank you both for your time and effort. The first suggestion does not do it for me. In Word the equation does not look nice. Meanwhile I tried something with MathML and I got something small actually working.