# Generating word documents with equations and formulae using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, python-docx

Is there any way to generate word documents with equations and formulae using python?
Now, I'm using [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to generate word documents. I have checked the documentation of python-docx but I didn't find anything related to formulae and equations.

I need to  both extract formulae from the word document as well as generate a new word document with that extracted formulae.

Is it possible in python to extract equations from word document and store it in a database or something and then generate a word document with that formulae and equations???

[image: Chemical equations]

EDIT: I have attached some of the equations I need to extract/generate

Comment: do you have a word docx example? have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover I didn't find any other options yet. I have added some equations that I need to extract/generate to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `python-docs` does not support adding math equations since "there is currently no API support for equations" ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/1011)).

Comment: So, is there any other way to do it? like another library written in any other programming language? I was thinking about C#.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if I'm understanding the cited statement correctly, this is simply not possible because there's no interface for any program to interact with or create equations in Word

Comment: An alternative could be to create the equation using a different library and export it as an image that you include in your document, but I'm not sure if that matches your expectations

Comment: I have seen a software that allows the user to upload word documents with equations and extracts that equations and allows the user to edit or rearrange equations and then finally gives a new word document with equations with all the modifications. The extracted equations is extracted as a equation not as an image.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61031355/3281097) on another question help?